# Let Hashem stop Bilam advising Bolok to arrange sinning with Ba'al Pe'or

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, parashat-balak

Why does HKB”H intervene (in [Parshas Bolok](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.22.2?lang=bi&with=Rashi&lang2=en) ) to stop Bilam cursing the Jewish people but does not intervene to stop Bilam giving the advice [to sin with Ba'al Pe'or](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.25.1?lang=bi&with=Rashi&lang2=en) .

Comment: Free will. God will not prevent us from doing the wrong thing. A curse by some distant gentile prophet is a different matter, because it does not require action on the part of the Jews.

Comment: From the [Chasam Sofer](https://www.sefaria.org/Chatam_Sofer_on_Torah%2C_Balak.51) and the [Malbim](https://www.sefaria.org/Malbim_on_Numbers.24.14.1) it sounds like Hashem had a problem specifically with Bilam and his cursing. Maybe because he was a prophet who chose to misuse his powers?

Comment: Intervene? Bilam asked Hashem for permission in the first case, not in the second

Comment: @RabbiKaii Not explicitly. Hashem came to Bilom. Bilom did not approach Hashem.

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok he made it clear that He wanted Hashem's input, Balak 22:8, right? He invited Hashem to give permission. Maybe that is implicit, but there is no such request for permission, implicit or otherwise, regarding the advice on Bal Peor

Comment: @RabbiKaii ok it seems as you say. BTW Rashi says " [AND I WILL GIVE YOU AN ANSWER] AS THE LORD SHALL SPEAK TO ME — If He advises me to go with people such as you I will go with you; but perhaps it is not compatible with His dignity to permit me to go except with princes greater than you. "